# sshd_config all parameters commented out

Tags: ssh, sshd

I've inherited administration of a server (and I am not really an admin) and unfortunately there are a ton of things I've never been exposed to.

All of the parameters in the sshd_config are commented out. ssh is working fine however. Does this mean that a default configuration is being used? What is the reason that the previous admin may have done this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This site is intended as a programming Q&A. For questions like this about how to use basic services, you might want to head over to http://SuperUser.com. Questions specific to unix and Linux environments belong at http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it means default configuration is being used. There is no particular reason, which can be connected to blank sshd_config. May be previous admin was debugging some sshd issues.

Answer (score 0):

The `sshd_config` contains all configuration options with default values by default. So the answer is that the previous admin was not doing anything with this configuration.

For the record, see the official upstream [`sshd_config`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/sshd_config), which now contains few non-commented lines, but the older versions or openbsd versions might not contain them.